# Как правильно очистить место на жестком диске для установки Linux Mint

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint, dual-boot

Собираюсь поставить Linux Mint на один из разделов жесткого диска (у меня на компьютере стоит win8, удалять её не собираюсь) ( Линукс ставлю первый раз. До этого пользовался ею только на virtualbox). Я его отформатировал, получилось 80 гб свободного места.
Вопросы:

1. Если я вообще удалю данный логический раздел, у меня получится свободное место, т.е при установке минта я выберу это свободное место - и у меня создастся новый раздел диска, с линуксом на борту?
2. Читал в туториалах, что можно сжать раздел диска. Если я выполню предыдущий пункт, то мне не придется ничего сжимать?
3. Как после установки линукса сделать "невидимыми" остальные разделы жесткого диска, чтобы я не мог с системы вообще ничего записать\прочитать на эти тома, кроме своего, на котором собственно установлена система?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Да. Получится свободное место, которое инсталлятор Mint'а разобьёт на нужные ему разделы. Разделов будет по меньшей мере два - один для системы, второй - раздел подкачки. Можно и без подкачки, но Linux'у это не очень нравится.
2. Не очень понятно что Вы имеете в виду. Можно сжать содержимое диска, например, при помощи встроенных функций NTFS, но размер раздела не уменьшится. А можно ***уменьшить раздел***, сохранив данные. Но на разделе должно быть свободное от данных место, которое и будет "откушено" при этой операции. Уменьшить раздел можно при помощи *GParted*. Вроде бы, можно это сделать и при установке, но я этого никогда не делал, поэтому не буду утверждать. Но в любом случае, если Вы уже создали свободный раздел, эта операция будет не нужна.
3. Чтобы работать с разделом в Linux, его нужно смонтировать. Если при установке Вы не укажете системе, что ей нужно монтировать другие разделы, то они будут не видны и, следовательно, ничего записать на них не удастся.

Учтите, что загрузчик Windows будет заменён загрузчиком *GRUB*. Если Вы потом удалите Linux, то потом с высокой степенью вероятности не сможете загрузиться вообще. Для восстановления работоспособности придётся восстанавливать загрузчик.

Answer (score 2):

1. если вы удалите логический диск то у вас будет неразмеченная область. Из нее надо будет создать том и отформатировать в подходящую для линукса ФС типа ext3. Если я не ошибаясь все это может инсталятор системы.
2. Сжатие раздела диска это превращение части его свободного пространства в неразмеченную область из которой можно будет содать отдельный том или добавить к другому диску (который рядом)
3. Если диски не будут смонтированы то их не будет видно.